# Is there always a canonical transformation such that the new Hamiltonian only depends on the new momenta?

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Given the Hamiltonian $H(x,p)$ of a system. Is there always a coordinate transformation such that the new Hamiltonian is $K(x',p')=K(p')$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Not globally. A Hamiltonian that only depends on momenta is automatically [Liouville integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability), but not all Hamiltonian systems are Liouville integrable.
- Locally, assuming various regularity conditions, one could in principle solve [Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) to perform a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT) and reach a vanishing Kamiltonian $K\equiv 0$.

Comment: @Qmechanic- I am reading this paper( http://cds.cern.ch/record/529134/files/0112010.pdf). In page 8 second paragraph, the author tells that we can always come up with such a transformation.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: What could be the canonical transformations which make 1-D harmonic oscillator and anharmonic oscillator locally indistinguishable?

Comment: The HJ equation points to some elliptic integral...